# Can't run RubyGems without sudo anymore

Tags: ruby, rubygems, osx-yosemite

I'm running OSX 10.10.5.

After updating rubygems to the latest version (2.4.8) I can't run gems without sudo anymore.

I get a simple

```
permission denied: myGem
```

The permissions of the file after installing it with

```
sudo gem install myGem
```

in /usr/bin are

```
-rwx------     1 root   wheel   531B Aug 24 15:13 myGem
```

I actually haven't tinkered with the permissions at all, that's why I'm a bit confused why its not working anymore.

```
~  ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]

~  gem --version 
2.4.8

~  gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-05-08 patchlevel 481) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
     - /Users/marcwustrack/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

Any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked around it now by installing rvm and reinstalling all gems I had so far.